# How to make Google Map Label Clickable in Android

Tags: android, dictionary, click, label

[image]

By default on google map app it shows all the transport label and other poi label which are clickable. How can i make them clickable in code, I tried groundoverlay listener and that doesnt work. Also in my app, these poi is not clickable, i want to make it clickable and display the description. How can i do it?

Comment: why not to make the click on the marker ?

Comment: No, by default in google map without searching anything, there are some poi overlaid on the map. but they are not clickable. I wonder any google api to do it.

Comment: Also, I have seen google places picker, I want the ui to be something like that, that i can click on the overlaid icon and retrieve information. but i want this to be integrated into my own map

Answer (score 0):

@user6491664 yeah by default the map POI's are not clickable. Make them clickable by implementing the GoogleMap.OnPoiClickListener in your class and set the OnPoiClickListener on the map by calling GoogleMap.setOnPoiClickListener(OnPoiClickListener).

see example below;

```
class MapPOIDemo extends AppCompatActivity implements
    OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnPoiClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mappoidemo);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        map.setOnPoiClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPoiClick(PointOfInterest poi) {
        //set TODO
    }
}
```